# AngularMaterial Dialog not open properly

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am setting up angular material dialog . But popup dialog loaded on the landing page

I downloaded source code from official website

https://stackblitz.com/angular/ngbdaexgmxr?file=app%2Fdialog-overview-example.ts

When i run the application , popup dialog loaded on the landing page ( parent page)

Need to open as a popup screen

Comment: As I checked the provided stackblitz nothing wrong with it, Can you please explain bit more

Comment: Kindly download the source code from 'https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview' . If we run the application from our local system, the output is not same as online editor means popup will load on same landing page.

Comment: So do you want to change the background color of dialog box?